# Output shapefile data type in Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, python-script-tool, parameters

I have to reproject a shapefile's coordinate system. To do that I am using Arcpy and I want to get an output to use it as input in other tool (in Model Builder).

Now I get an output, but I cannot use it as input in model builder's tool. I am not programing well when I process the output shapefile.

The code is:

`def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""`

```
 # First parameter

    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Shape entrada a reproyectar",
        name="in_features",
        datatype="DEShapefile",
            parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

# Second parameter

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Imagen satelite de la cual se utilizara el CRS",
            name="raster",
        datatype="GPRasterLayer",
            parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

# Third parameter
     param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Shape de salida",
        name="out_features",
        datatype="DEShapefile",
            parameterType="Derived",
        direction="Output")

    parameters = [param0, param1, param2]
    return parameters`
```

`def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""`

```
shape= parameters[0].valueAsText
raster= parameters[1].valueAsText
output=parameters[2].valueAsText
#-----------------------------

desc = arcpy.Describe(shape)

out_CRS = arcpy.Describe (raster).spatialReference

output=arcpy.Project_management(shape, desc.path + "\\" + desc.baseName + "_Rprj.shp", out_CRS)


return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `output` but you are not creating it as a result of Project tool. Check out your `execute` function. It collects `output` from the second parameter as text and this variable gets overwritten by the Project tool. By the way, many ArcGIS tools return `result` object and you need to specify output location by calling its first element to be on the safe side. In your case,

`output=arcpy.Project_management(shape, desc.path + "\\" + desc.baseName + "_Rprj.shp", out_CRS)[0]`

will assign `desc.path + "\\" + desc.baseName + "_Rprj.shp"` to `output`.

Still it does not resolve your issue. I think you should set the parameter after Project tool, i.e.,

`output=arcpy.Project_management(shape, desc.path + "\\" + desc.baseName + "_Rprj.shp", out_CRS)[0]`

`arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, output)`

More clearly, here is a possible `execute` def:

```
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        desc = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0])
        out_CRS = arcpy.Describe(parameters[1]).spatialReference
        output = arcpy.Project_management(parameters[0].valueAsText, desc.path + "\\" + desc.baseName + "_Rprj.shp", out_CRS)
        # That's what @Hornbydd suggested in the comments
        my_output = output.getOutput(0)
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, my_output)
        return
```

Here is a snip of my toolbox:

[image]

Lastly, this is the snip of Reprojector tool in Model Builder after a successful run.

[image]

Comment: To compliment this answer I would like to add; as you correctly identify `output` is actually a result object. To avoid confusion I would have called it something like `objRes`. Then you retrieve the output of the tool as `myFeatureClass = objRes.getOutput(0)`. It is then clear _exactly_ what it is. I often see peoples code passing result objects around their code as if they are datasets which makes it difficult to read.

Comment: @fatih_dur, I modify the code but I cannot obtain the output. Can you modify the code? Thanks

Comment: @MikV89, Did you try to add this python tool to a model builder? What do you see? I will replicate your example and add a snapshot!